# How should i proceed to achieve persistence with ESPER(with WSO2) in case of failover without using ESPERHA?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, esper, wso2-cep

I am using WSO2 CEP-Server with esper as backEND-Runtime.WSO2 has provided persistence with siddhi(backEnd-runtime) using cassandra.I need to implement persistence with ESPER-CEP engine.
Any thought would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EsperHA seems perfect for that. See www.espertech.com

Comment: Thanks for your thought on this!!, but esperHA is available as free in its trial version only.
Could you please assist on customization of wso2(esper as Runtime) for persistence.